# How to turn this bar graph to rectangle boxes in python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this code which gives bar graph when displaying output, but what (x0, x1, y0, y1) coordinates should i use to get rectangular boxes instead of bar lines ? I want to get all the rectangles on the same line with same height and width.

```
def drawData(data, colorArray):
    canvas.delete("all")
    c_height = 380
    c_width = 600
    x_width = c_width / (len(data) + 1)
    offset = 30
    spacing = 10
    normalizedData = [i / max(data) for i in data]
    for i, height in enumerate(normalizedData):
        # top left
        x0 = i * x_width + offset + spacing
        y0 = c_height - height * 340
        # bottom right
        x1 = (i + 1) * x_width + offset
        y1 = c_height

        canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=colorArray[i])
        canvas.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor=SW, text=str(data[i]))

    root.update_idletasks()
```

This is the dimensions of my canvas -

```
UI_frame = Frame(root, width= 600, height=200, bg='red')
UI_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=650, height=380, bg='white')
canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
```

Comment: have you tried simply adding a small number to the y1 coordinate to see what happens?

Comment: It may be due to that `spacing` is roughly the same as `x_width`. Suggest setting `spacing` to at most half of `x_width`. Also `offset` should be taken into account when calculating `x_width`: `x_width = (c_width - offset) / len(data)`.

Comment: You might try `y1 = y0 + x_width / 2`